# Let's Encrypt Token Will Not Save

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, encryption, gitlab

Trying to add SSL to a gitlab server using Let's Encrypt and Certbot.

I can save a test.txt in the webroot and access it in /.well-known/acme-challenge/

I have changed the setting so /var/www/letsencrypt/ is the root for the token to be accessed.

The settings in the gitlab.rb are:

```
    nginx['custom_gitlab_server_config'] = "location ^~ /.well-known { root /var/www/letsencrypt; }"
```

The error I am seeing is:

```
    Failed authorization procedure. gitlab.example.co.uk (http-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: Fetching http://gitlab.example.co.uk/.well-known/acme-challenge/arUuWGLPGjQRw333SPHMzzlNezA1Zitjw4a9BrTFJ7w: Timeout
```

I have been searching for days not, but no luck.